# Is there an easy way to compare matching elements of data frame from a list and replace into the data frame?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame of different observations:

```
    df <- data.frame('Time' = c(1058,672,1153,1321,1408), 'Event' = c('LU6/LU12','LU48','LU12','LU6/LU12','LU6'), 'Name' = NA)
```

And also this reference list, in which the first element of each vector is the Time and the rest are the Events done:

```
ReferenceList <- list('A' = c('500','LU24','LU12','LU6'),
                      'B' = c('1000','LU48','LU24','LU12','LU6'),
                      'C' = c('1500','LU48','LU24','LU12','LU6'))
```

I would like to replace the NA values of the Name column for the name of each vector in the list, considering the smallest difference between the observed Time and the reference and in which vector from the list the Event appears. For this case I would obtain this data frame:

```
Time    Event     Name
1058    LU6/LU12  B
672     LU48      B
1153    LU12      B
1321    LU6/LU12  C
1408    Lu6       C
```

Is there an R function to do this or a straightfoward way avoiding for loops?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you propose should happen on mis-matches, i.e., `"LU6/LU12"`?

Comment: What I mean to say is that your `ReferenceList` does not contain `"LU6/LU12"` which is in your `df`.

Comment: LU6/LU12 means that both LU6 and LU12 has happened. Sorry for the lack of information.
In this case, I would like to get the element from the list the contains LU6 or LU12 and has the smallest difference between time

Comment: You need to be clear about that. This question turned from a straight-forward `merge` (or `*_join`) operation into a fuzzy, regex, or multi-match merge.

Comment: Indeed. The real data frame is way worse than this and I had to do some operations regarding regex to identify the correct elements. I used too many for loops, which I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this seemingly-convoluted approach, using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

First, I think your current storage of `ReferenceList` is a bad idea. It's much better to store numbers as numbers.

```r
ref2 <- stack(ReferenceList) %>%
  transmute(Name = as.character(ind), values) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarize(
    Time2 = as.integer(grep("^\\d+$", values, value = TRUE)),
    Event = list(grep("\\D", values, value = TRUE))
  ) %>%
  unnest(Event)
ref2
# # A tibble: 11 x 3
#    Name  Time2 Event
#    <chr> <int> <chr>
#  1 A       500 LU24 
#  2 A       500 LU12 
#  3 A       500 LU6  
#  4 B      1000 LU48 
#  5 B      1000 LU24 
#  6 B      1000 LU12 
#  7 B      1000 LU6  
#  8 C      1500 LU48 
#  9 C      1500 LU24 
# 10 C      1500 LU12 
# 11 C      1500 LU6
```

That format is a lot more usable (IMHO), and merges well later.

From here,

```r
df %>%
  select(-Name) %>%
  mutate(
    rn = row_number(),
    Event = as.character(Event),
    Event_list = strsplit(Event, "/")
  ) %>%
  unnest(Event_list) %>%
  left_join(ref2, by = c("Event_list" = "Event")) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  slice(which.min(abs(Time - Time2))) %>%
  select(Time, Event, Name) %>%
  ungroup()
# Adding missing grouping variables: `rn`
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#      rn  Time Event    Name 
#   <int> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>
# 1     1  1058 LU6/LU12 B    
# 2     2   672 LU48     B    
# 3     3  1153 LU12     B    
# 4     4  1321 LU6/LU12 C    
# 5     5  1408 LU6      C
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's very enlightening! I will apply your approach to my data set, I'm confident it's gonna be useful.